# curve_fit seems to overestimate error of estimated parameters

Tags: python, curve-fitting, scipy-optimize, pcov

I have some data from the lab, which I'm fitting to the function

f(s, params) = amp * (s/sp) / (1 + s/sp + 1.041) + bg (couldn't figure out how to type set this)

I set `absolute_sigma=True` on `curve_fit` to get the absolute uncertainties of the parameters (sp, amp, bg), but the calculated error from `np.sqrt(np.diag(pcov))` seems unreasonable. See the plot below. The blue dots are data. The red line is the `f(s, *popt)`. The green line replaces the optimal sp value with sp - it's error as calculated from `np.sqrt(np.diag(pcov))`. The orange line is sp + the same value.

[image]

I would expect the +/- lines to be much tighter to the red line.

Here's a minimal example:

```
# Function for fitting
def scattering_rate(s, sp, amp, bg):
    return amp * (s/sp) / (1 + s/sp + (-20/19.6)**2) + bg

# data
s = np.array([0.6, 1.2, 2.3, 4.3, 8.1, 15.2, 28.5, 53.4])
y = np.array([8.6, 8.5, 8.9, 9.5, 10.6, 12.6, 15.5, 18.3])

# Fit data to saturated scattering rate
popt, pcov = curve_fit(scattering_rate, s, y, absolute_sigma=True)
print('Fit parameters', popt)
print('Fit uncertainties', np.sqrt(np.diag(pcov)))

# Construct fit from optimized parameters
fit_s = np.linspace(np.min(s), np.max(s), 100)
fit = scattering_rate(fit_s, *popt)

# Consider one error difference in sp value
fit_plus_err = saturation_power(fit_s, popt[0] + np.sqrt(np.diag(pcov))[0], popt[1], popt[2])
fit_minus_err = saturation_power(fit_s, popt[0] - np.sqrt(np.diag(pcov))[0], popt[1], popt[2])

# Plot
plt.plot(s, y, '-o', markeredgecolor='k', label='data')
plt.plot(fit_s, fit_plus_err, label='sp + err')
plt.plot(fit_s, fit_minus_err, label='sp - err')
plt.plot(fit_s, fit, '-r', label='opt sp')
plt.xlabel('s')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.legend()
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Edit

Following @jlandercy's answer, we need the error bars of the original data which are `y_err = array([0.242, 0.231, 0.282, 0.31 , 0.373])`. Including that in `curve_fit`'s `sigma` argument, the results look much better though still a bit distance
[image]

Comment: Please share a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Just edited the original post with an example

Comment: What is the function `saturation_power`? How is it defined, from what package it comes from ?

Comment: It's a physics equation specific to the data we are taking. If you really want to know, it comes from the scattering rate of a ytterbium ion fluorescencing under a detuned laser beam. The equation is really not the issue though. My question is why would curve_fit compute such a large variance on the fit parameters when the data is so close to the fit.

Comment: Do you have some estimate for uncertainty on y ?

Comment: I think the biggest problem is the way the error bound is calculated. It is not done by adding the single parameter error to each parameter and evaluate the function like this. you need to do proper error propagation including correlation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Why

When using `absolute_sigma=True` your are advised to feed the `sigma` switch as well, if not they are replaced by `1.` making Chi Square loss function behaves as RSS and `pcov` becomes somehow meaningless if your uncertainty are not unitary.

### Fix

Provides uncertainty or an estimate of it as well to get a meaningful `pcov` matrix.

Setting `sigma` to `0.15` with your data drastically improve the `pcov` matrix while keeping the Chi Square statistics significant:

```
sy = np.full(y.size, 0.15)
popt, pcov = curve_fit(scattering_rate, s, y, sigma=sy, absolute_sigma=True)
np.sqrt(pcov)

# array([[3.25479068, 2.07084837, 0.45391942],
#       [2.07084837, 1.35773667, 0.2563505 ],
#       [0.45391942, 0.2563505 , 0.09865549]])
```

[image]
[image]

#### Update

You have two direct options to improve the error:

- Collect more points (5 points for 3 parameters leave a Chi Square with `dof=2` which is very asymmetric);
- Reduce the uncertainty on `y`.

Figure below shows the impact on a synthetic dataset with equivalent parameters of yours:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Ah, thank you! The error bars on the data are `array([0.242, 0.231, 0.282, 0.31 , 0.373])`. It gives much closer results though still a bit distant

Comment: Updated the answer with two options to improve the error.